# JavaScript conditonal statement behaving differently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, postman

I have an endpoint `localhost:3000/users/add` and `localhost:3000/users/login`. When a user logs in the server returns a Jsonwebtoken with two properties in the following format: `user: { username: 'user_name', access_level: 4 }`. I then have an `auth` custom middleware that validates the access_level of the user and I use it to protect `localhost:3000/users/add`. The route then looks as follows:

router.js:

```
router.post('/add', auth, async (req, res, next) => {
    // get user input
    const user = req.body;
    try {
        const data = await Helper.validateUserInput(user)

        // encrypt password
        const hash = await Helper.encryptPassword(data.value.password)
        if(hash) {
            const databaseUser = new User({
                'username': data.value.username,
                'password': hash,
                'access_level': data.value.access_level
            });
            // persist to database
            const saved = await databaseUser.save();
            console.log(saved);
            res.status(200).json({success: true, message: `User successfully added`})

        }

    }
    // if there's an error
    catch(error){
        if(error.hasOwnProperty('code')) {
            const error_code = error.code;
            if(error_code === 11000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false, 
                    error_message: error.errmsg
                })
            }else {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false, 
                    error: error
                })
            }
        }  
    }      
});
```

The auth middleware function is as follows:

auth.js:

```
const Helper = require('../helpers/helpers')

module.exports = function async (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.query.token;
    if(!token) {
        res.status(403).json({
            success: false,
            error_message: `Forbiden - Invalid credentials!`
        })
    }
    Helper.verify_token(token)
    .then((user) => {
        const { access_level } = user.user;
        console.log(access_level)
        if(access_level != 4) {
            res.status(401).json ({
                success: false,
                error_message: `Unauthorized - Invalid credentials!`
            })
        }else {
            next()
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(403).json({
            success: false,
            error_message: `Forbiden - Invalid credentials!`
        })
    })
}
```

I then try to access the protected route and Postman just hangs and does not give a response. What is strange though is that if I change the `if statement` in `auth.js`eg:

```
if(access_level != 1) {
   res.status(401).json ({
      success: false,
         error_message: `Unauthorized - Invalid credentials!`
      })
   }else {
     next()
 }
```

everything works fine. I really don't understand what the issue is here.

Comment: Ok, so the value of `access_level` is affecting the outcome. Is some other route then responding to the request?

Comment: Any other condition in the statement works, however, that specific condition `if (access_level != 4)` does not work

Comment: try giving the response in the else of if(hash). maybe the hash returned is undefined or false and there is no else block so the postman is hanging till the response.

Comment: Can you please post what is the data you are sending? Cause if you are sending 4 as access level then when it works it is processed via else statement, and when it hangs it is processed via if statement

Comment: Can you add return in front of `res.status(401)` like this and try again? `return res.status(401)`

Comment: @dima golovin the data decoded from the token in the format: `user: { username: 'user_name', access_level: 4 }` where `access_level` is a number from 1 to 4

Answer (score 0):

Chane the add function

```
router.post('/add', auth, async (req, res, next) => {
    // get user input
    const user = req.body;
    try {
        const data = await Helper.validateUserInput(user)

        // encrypt password
        const hash = await Helper.encryptPassword(data.value.password)
        if (hash) {
            const databaseUser = new User({
                'username': data.value.username,
                'password': hash,
                'access_level': data.value.access_level
            });
            // persist to database
            const saved = await databaseUser.save();
            console.log(saved);
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: `User successfully added` })
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: "Please try again"
            })
        }

    }
    // if there's an error
    catch (error) {
        if (error.hasOwnProperty('code')) {
            const error_code = error.code;
            if (error_code === 11000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    error_message: error.errmsg
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: false,
                    error: error
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: error
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And change the auth middleware

```
const Helper = require('../helpers/helpers')

module.exports = function async (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.query.token;
    if(!token) {
        res.status(403).json({
            success: false,
            error_message: `Forbiden - Invalid credentials!`
        })
    }
   else{
    Helper.verify_token(token)
    .then((user) => {
        const { access_level } = user.user;
        console.log(access_level)
        if(access_level != 4) {
            res.status(401).json ({
                success: false,
                error_message: `Unauthorized - Invalid credentials!`
            })
        }else {
            next()
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(403).json({
            success: false,
            error_message: `Forbiden - Invalid credentials!`
        })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference to the logic I have? Can you please elaborate

Comment: Kimar another thing this throws an error, the `else statement` after `try catch`

Comment: 1. you are not handling if Helper.encryptPassword(data.value.password) is failed , you only checking code exits or not in error, what about if code not exists in error.

2. In authentication middleware  validation still execute if token exists or not exists because you just added **!token**

Comment: It's a plain object with two properties `{ user: { username: 'user_name', access_level: 4 } }`